# str.replace com javascript só funciona uma vez!

Tags: javascript, replace

Bom dia a todos!!
Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado no código:

```
function () {
        var x = infoComentarioStrReplace.replace(" $$ ","*")//var resposta = infoComentarioStrReplace.replace("$", "#");
        console.log("=>"+x);
    }
```

esse código pega a string e substitui todos os "$$" por * , porém, quando lanço o valor de teste $$ $$ na variável ele só substitui um conjunto de $$ ou seja, ele me retorna:

```
apenas um teste*$$
```

alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado aqui???
obrigado pela atenção!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O replace do javascript substitui apenas a primeira ocorrência da string que você passa como parâmetro.

uma solução seria fazer algo assim:

```
while(infoComentarioStrReplace.indexOf(" $$") >= 0) {
    infoComentarioStrReplace = infoComentarioStrReplace.replace(" $$ ","*");
}
```

Comment: obrigado!! deu certo!